# Fast way to copy pixels belonging to the circles

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vectorization

I have an initial grayscale image `img` in `double` format with a number of circles of the same radii and column vectors with circle centers coordinates `x` and `y`. I need to copy all the pixels belonging to the circles to an array `cpix`. So far I came up only with the most blunt solution using `for` loops. Is there a way to vectorize this code or just make it work faster?

```
% x(:) - vector with a few circles center X coordinates
% y(:) - vector with a few circles center Y coordinates
d = 27;                  %diameter
r = floor(d/2);          %radius
cpix = double(zeros(d,d,size(x,1)));

for iCent = 1:size(x,1)  %for each circle
    for ix = 1:d
        for iy = 1:d
            if ((ix-r)^2 + (iy-r)^2) < r^2
                cpix(iy,ix,iCent) = img(iy+y(iCent)-r,ix+x(iCent)-r);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can a circle be close to the border of the images ? and what should happen in this case ?

Comment: No, the circles are more than a radius `r` away from the borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only one loop (for each circle) you can use a mask like a disk to select the appropriate pixels from your image.
Start with your initial code.

```
% x(:) - vector with a few circles center X coordinates
% y(:) - vector with a few circles center Y coordinates
d = 27;                  %diameter
r = floor(d/2);          %radius
cpix = double(zeros(d,d,size(x,1)));
```

Now create the mask with the desired radius. It can be done easily if you have the **Image Processing Toolbox**.

```
h = fspecial('disk', r);
h = h > 0;
```

Then use this mask in a loop to select the desired region.

```
for i = 1:size(x,1)
    cpix(:,:,i) = h .* img(x(i)-r:x(i)+r, y(i)-r:y(i)+r);
end
```

Since you only create the mask once, it should be faster than calculating it for each circle.

You can do it one go if you build a 3D mask. If `a x b` is the size of your image and `n` is the number of circles, then the mask would be `a x b x n`. If you `repmat` your image to a stack of size `n`. You can then use `.*` multiplication to get your final result. The result, however, will be a stack of `a x b` images and not `d x d` as you mentioned.
Not sure if it will be faster because you'll have anyway to loop it during the creation of the 3D mask. If the mask is built only once and used in a lot of images though, it could be worth it.

Comment: Thanks! That's a perfect solution, works in just 0.008290 seconds compared to 4.594374 with my original code. The only thing I needed to change is img indexing - y and x are swapped so the line looks like `cpix(:,:,i) = h .* img(y(i)-r:y(i)+r, x(i)-r:x(i)+r);`

Comment: Please notify somewhere that the users will require the **Image Processing Toolbox** to run your solution. It may lead to less frustrations if later user try this code and it fails without them knowing why.

Comment: Thanks @hoki! I added the Image Processing Toolbox note.

Answer (score 1):

considering your image is double and has 1 layer, for the center of the circle being at `[cx,cy]` you can get a matrix, the same size as the main image, with logical values in which `1` specifies that the pixel is inside the circle (radius = `r`) and `0` otherwise.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(img,1),1:size(img,2));
C = bsxfun(@le,(X-cx).^2+(Y-cy).^2 ,r);
```

finally, `img(C)` includes all the valid pixel values.

**Example with a single circle:**

```
r = 5;
cx=100;
cy=100;
Id = im2double(imread('myimage.png'));
Id1 = Id(:,:,1);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(Id1,1),1:size(Id1,2));
C = bsxfun(@le,(X-cx).^2+(Y-cy).^2 ,r);

length(Id1(C))
ans = 
      21
```

**With more than one circle**, you need to have a for-loop

```
cx = [100,110,120];
cy = [150,170,190];

for ii = 1:length(cx);
    C = bsxfun(@le,(X-cx(ii)).^2+(Y-cy(ii)).^2 ,r);
end
```

The other parts of the code remain intact.

Comment: That's one way, but may be you could extend your example to deal with an _array_ of center `cx` and `cy`. The OP seems to have a few to deal with.

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion, that's an interesting method. But the point is to get the 3-d array, with a 3rd dimension equal to the number of circles

Comment: Complete vectorization might not benefit here, so that one-loop looks justified to me. Good job!

Comment: After execution of the proposed code, I need to do the segmentation again in order to get the required array, where all the information about the disk area inside the circles will be indexed in the 3rd dimension. To process the sample image 966x966px with 350 circles of radius=15, it takes 4.59 sec with my code and 3.60 sec with the code proposed by NKN (keeping in mind that after the execution I would need to do some kind of loop again to get the desired array)
So is there a way to make vectorized operation that yields specified array? I couldnt come up with the solution based on meshgrid yet

Answer (score 0):

I have a open source library [**pixelscan**](https://github.com/dpmcmlxxvi/pixelscan) which can scan pixels in a variety of spatial patterns (circles, rings, snakes, grid, randomwalk). There are also various spatial transformations that can be applied (e.g., rotation, scaling, clipping). It is a python library but you the relevant code could be trivially ported to MATLAB.